# Remove border after arrow in angular-tree

Tags: angular

I am implementing angular-tree

[angular2-tree](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/v7.2.0/docs/events#activate)

I want to remove the border lines, how can I do that.

Please help

[image]

Comment: In official documentation I am seeing there is no border line! which version of angular tree you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In https://angular2-tree.readme.io/v7.2.0/docs/styling under the branch lines theme, you can see that borders are made on classes `.node-content-wrapper::before` and `.tree-children::after`.

So try with this

```
.node-content-wrapper::before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
}

.tree-children::after {
  border-left: none;
}
```